# Django join query set based on condition

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

**Models are given below:**

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    wid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1000)])
    wname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Invitation(models.Model):
    iid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1000)])
    invite_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitation_uid2", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, related_name="invitation_wid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to get the list of workspaces based on invite_to

**"select * from Workspace where wid in (select workspace from Invitation where invite_to = 1)"**

The above query in ORM type

Comment: Why do you want to make a SQLite joint queryset if you can make this query through Django's QuerySet?

Comment: Django is also fine @AuroraWang

Comment: Can't you do something like: "Workspace.objects.filter(invitation_wid__invite_to__id=1)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can do it using [Django's QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/):

```
Workspace.objects.filter(invitation_wid__invite_to__id=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the user id, you can use the double underscore `__` syntax to filter across relations:

```
workspaces = Workspace.objects.filter(invitation_wid__invite_to__id=1)
```